# Chai expect objects inside array to not include multiple properties

Tags: javascript, testing, chai

How to assert that all objects inside array do not include multiple properties.
Example all of them should not include keys "email" and "phone".

```
const myArray = [
   {name: "John Doe", email: "john@gmail.com", phone: "9xxxxxxxxxx"},
   {name: "Jane Doe", email: "jane@gmail.com", phone: "9xxxxxxxxxx"},
   {name: "Johny Doe"}
]

// this seems to do what I want 
// but doesn't "something" check if any object passes the test?
expect(myArray).to.contain.something.that.does.not.include.any.keys("email", "phone")
```

Using `chai-things`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your array for elements having both keys set:

`myArray.filter(a => a.email && a.phone)`

and expect the count is 0:

```
expect(myArray.filter(a => a.email && a.phone)).to.be.an('array').that.is.empty;
```

Comment: I know I can filter the array and even assert each element individually. I was hoping to know more about chai and thought if there was a way to do it using only chai. Could you give me your opinion in doing it this way? is it completely acceptable or could there be a better way?